# Is this sentence pattern possible?

Tags: grammar

Is this pattern possible?

> I will mention other issues, to say nothing of our debt, in this discussion.

"Other" comes first, but is it ok?

The import of it is, "our debt and other issues."

Is this kind of logical inversion, if you will, possible?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what your question is.  Are you asking whether the sentence "I will mention other issues, to say nothing of our debt, in this discussion." is grammatically and idiomatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

It would be clearer to say "I will mention other issues, especially our debt, in this discussion."

Your sentence is grammatically correct, but it does not have the correct meaning. "To say nothing of" is a phrase used when you are literally not saying anything further about a topic. For example, I could say, "This house is very dirty, to say nothing of your room." 
Source: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/to+say+nothing+of

Since it seems you intend to speak about your debt in detail later on, you would be better off avoiding the phrase.

Note: "Import" has a completely different meaning than "importance," which is what you should say when something is important.

Comment: The use of "import" to mean "importance" is *completely* acceptable in the correct context. ("I bear news of great import!") The sentence user4215 has "import" in would *not* be correct if "importance" were used instead. It is, instead, a rarely-seen version of definition 3 at http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/import?s=t . (I wouldn't use it, but it doesn't seem to be incorrect.)